# Do you know a quick way to trasforme a list in a list of lists in this way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

This is the input list in witch every elemente of the list contain one string of only 0 or 1:

```
input = ['00001001010', '1010100000100', '10100010010001']
```

I would like to create to transform this list, in a list of lists, where each one of the sublists contain for each element each figure(converted in intager) previously contained in the string element of the starting list.

therefore i would have as a return:

```
output = [[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0], [1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0], [1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]]
```

I tryed all kind of lists comprehension, but i ended up with some computational expensive code for problem like that, especially because my program receives in input lists of this type but fifty times longer .
Surely there is an optimal way to do it but I can't find it.
Any of you have an idea?
Maybe there is a way to take advantage of the fact that strings can only contain characters 0 and 1.

Answer (score 4):

Try this way -

```
inlist = ['00001001010', '1010100000100', '10100010010001']
outlist = [[int(c) for c in st] for st in inlist]
print(outlist)
```

The outer list comprehension will loop over each string (denoted by `st`). The inner list comprehension just loop over each character of that string (`st`) and turns them into integer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map(int, list)`:

*(don't use [`built-in function`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-functions) as variable (here you use `input` as variable, If you write `input()` you get an error))*

```
>>> lst = ['00001001010', '1010100000100', '10100010010001']

>>> output = [list(map(int,l)) for l in lst]

>>> output
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```